# Missing Windows Phone templates in VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm following the tutorial for page navigation on the Windows Phone platform found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx

In the tutorial it says that I ahve to add a so called **Windows Phone Portrait Page** but the problem is, that nothing like that appears in the options after I open the "Add" menu. I've installed the Windows Phone SDK, otherwise I wouldn't be able to start this project to begin with, but the template appears to be missing.

Any help on the matter would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Tools` -> `Extensions and Updates` -> `Online` -> `Visual Studio Gallery` -> `Template` and finding them there. There's lots of different templates you can choose from.

It also appears that this tutorial is for Windows Phone 8, if you've got the latest 8.1 updates these templates may have since been renamed to Basic Page.